# UVC Certified: FaceVsion’s TouchCam N1

Tags: 10.10, webcam, skype, cheese

Does anyone know if FaceVsion’s TouchCam N1 is UVC certified, or if it works with Ubuntu 10.10?

If so does it work with cheese, and or skype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have that same camera and have had no problems with the microphone and video, yes it works fine with Skype as well.